# How to optimize inverse pattern matching in Postgresql?

Tags: postgresql

I have Pg version 13.

```
CREATE TABLE test_schemes (
    pattern  TEXT  NOT NULL,
    some_code   TEXT  NOT NULL
);
```

Example data

```
----------- | -----------
pattern     | some_code
----------- | -----------
__3_        | c1
__34        | c2
1_3_        | a12
_7__        | a10
7138        | a19
_123|123_   | a20
___253      | a28
253         | a29
2_1         | a30
```

This table have about 300k rows. I want to optimize simple query like

```
SELECT * FROM test_schemes where '1234' SIMILAR TO pattern
```

```
----------- | -----------
pattern     | some_code
----------- | -----------
__3_        | c1
__34        | c2
1_3_        | a12
_123|123_   | a20
```

The problem is that this simple query will do a full scan of 300k rows to find all the matches. Given this design, how can I make the query faster (any use of special index)?

Comment: First question should probably be how to make it correct.  Your example does not actually return a20.

Comment: @jjanes thanks I mistakenly changed from SIMILAR TO to LIKE. My original code is using SIMILAR TO.

Comment: SIMILAR TO is extraordinarily slower than LIKE.  If `|` is the only feature you use, perhaps you could decompose that into a list of LIKE patterns with the same some_code.

Answer (score 0):

Internally, `SIMILAR TO` works similar to regexes, which would be evident by running an `EXPLAIN` on the query. You may want to just switch to regexes straight up, but it is also worth looking at `text_pattern_ops` indexes to see if you can improve the performance.

Comment: Thank you but I believe that `text_pattern_ops` will help if predicate is of this nature `pattern SIMILAR TO '1234' ` but in this case it is the other way around `'1234' SIMILAR TO pattern `

Answer (score 0):

If the pipe is the only feature of SIMILAR TO (other than those present in LIKE) which you use, then you could process it into a form you can use with the much faster LIKE.

```
SELECT * FROM test_schemes where '1234' LIKE any(string_to_array(pattern,'|'))
```

In my hands this is about 25 times faster, and gives the same answer as your example on your example data (augmented with a few hundred thousand rows of garbage to get the table row count up to about where you indicated).  It does assume there is no escaping of any pipes.

If you store the data already broken apart, it is about 3 times faster yet, but of course give cosmetically different answers.

```
create table test_schemes2 as select unnest as pattern, somecode from test_schemes, unnest(string_to_array(pattern,'|'));
SELECT * FROM test_schemes2 where '1234' LIKE pattern;
```